# Hide a text input on a dialog box of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, hide

I'm working on a plugin in CKEditor which have as a goal to hide or show element depending on which of my check box is checked. I have those element defined :

```
contents :
            [
                {
                    id : 'tab1',
                    label : 'Configuration Basique',
                    elements :
                    [
                        {
                            type : 'checkbox',
                            id : 'check',
                            label : 'Vers une page web',
                            'default' : 'unchecked',
                            onClick : function(){

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type : 'text',
                            id : 'title',
                            label : 'Explanation',
                        }    
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id : 'tab2',
                    label : 'Advanced Settings',
                    elements :
                    [
                        {
                            type : 'text',
                            id : 'id',
                            label : 'Id'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

so now what i would like to do is to hide no disable the text input with the label and print it only when the box is checked. So i've seen that i should use something like that :

```
onLoad : function(){
                this.getContentElement('tab1','title').disable();
        },
```

but the thing is i don't want to disable it i want to hide and then print it if the user check the box (which is why i put a onClick function in my checkbox). i've tryed to use the hide() function but it doesn't work and also the setAttribute('style','display : none;')
Tia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox definition is correct but there's no such thing like `onClick` property in dialog `uiElement` definition. All you got to do is to attach some listeners and toggle your field. Here you go:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( isThisYourDialog? ) {

        ...

        // Toggle your field when checkbox is clicked or dialog loaded.
        // You can also use getInputElement to retrieve element and hide(), show() etc.
        function toggleField( field, check ) {
            field[ check.getValue() ? 'enable' : 'disable' ]();
        }

        var clickListener;

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
            var check = this.getContentElement( 'tab1', 'check' ),

                // The element of your checkbox.
                input = check.getInputElement(),

                // Any field you want to toggle.
                field = this.getContentElement( 'tab1', 'customField' );

            clickListener = input.on( 'click', function() {
                toggleField( field, check );
            });

            // Toggle field immediately on show.
            toggleField( field, check );
        }

        dialogDefinition.onHide = function() {
            // Remove click listener on hide to prevent multiple
            // toggleField calls in the future.
            clickListener.removeListener();
        }

        ...
    }
});
```

More docs: [uiElement API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.uiElement), [dialog definition API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition).

Comment: Thank you man :D it worked :) the onClick thig i found it here http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.checkbox.html  i guess it's depricated

Answer (score 5):

If you actually want to hide (and not disable) the element you can do this using

```
this.getContentElement('tab1','title').getElement().hide();
```

The extra getElement() call returns the litteral DOM object for your contentElement object, so you can call hide()/show() at will on it.

Answer (score 3):

The onClick properties is available and does work on uiElement although it is not documented. The biggest problem is the definition of "this" is not the same inside the event than other place in the config. You first have to get the *dialog* to get other fields:

```
{
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'check',
    label: 'check',
    onClick: function() {
        var dialog = this.getDialog()
        if(this.getValue()){
            dialog.getContentElement('tab1','title' ).disable();
        } else {
            dialog.getContentElement('tab1','title' ).enable()
        }
    }
}
```